# How to send frames to the surfaceFlinger in android?

Tags: android

i am creating a simple app, something like client/server.

from server android device i want to send some frames to the client android device,
and this frames have to be displayed on the client device using surfaceflinger.
how can i achieve this?
i referred [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076529/surfaceflinger-test-program).

i dont know how these frames will be sent to client
and will be received & displayed using surfaceflinger.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing an app to be deployed on commercial devices via the Play store or otherwise want to make sure your app is compatible, you should not try to use Surfaceflinger directly.  It's not considered a "stable" API in the NDK so you cannot link against it like you can bionic.  If your app is written in Java, SurfaceView is what you want to use.

Comment: i want to design something like a vnc app which sends frames from remote device and will displayed on client device. there is any way to do this? i read about it and found that if i want to achieve my objective i'l need to send some frames to the surface flinger

Comment: Ah, that would be a problem then.  The standard SDK APIs do not allow you to have access to the raw flinger and capture screen data from any app.

Comment: i know it is possible to do...juss cant figure out how :(